Honeywell RTH6580WF. Need to connect new c wire
Having trouble figuring out how to connect the c wire. I have a Taco SR503 that has a 24 VAC COM terminal. 2 zones on a boiler system that are controlled by 2 wire thermostats. Tried connecting the new thermostat with a short three wire connection at the Taco. Red and white wires to the zone 1 terminals and green C wire to the 24VAC terminal. No power seems to be reaching the thermostat. Am I missing something?

Find the transformer on that PCB, and there will be the C wire

Thank you for the response, but not sure what you mean? The green terminal in the photo has a 24VAC on one side and COM on the other side. I assumed I could attach the c wire to either. Is it as simple as moving the wire from the terminal next to 24VAC to the other next to COM?

So I moved the c wire from the 24VAC to the COM side of that connector on the Taco. Connected by short wires at the Taco, the thermostat powered right up. So I ran a 3 wire thermostat wire (about a 30 foot run). Connected the new Honeywell Stat. No power. I'm baffled. Any advice for me?

You need closed loop, both the 24V and the COM have to go together
